# Is it possible to maintain the torque of a DC motor whilst changing its speed by using simple parts?

Tags: motor, dc

I’m currently conducting an investigation as part of an introduction to electricity as part of a physics course where I am required to gather quantitative and qualitative data regarding the speed and torque of a DC motor. I am stuck on finding a way to maintain the relatively constant torque whilst changing its speed. I have suggested the use of a hydraulic brake by using syringes but have been informed that it must be done through electrical means. I understand that precision is almost impossible as a result of the simplicity of the parts but is there a way to achieve this using the following materials list? Apologies for my lack of knowledge.

List of materials:

- Alligator wires
- Knife switches
- DC motor
- Resistors
- Potentiometers
- Power supply with a voltage knob control
- Data logger + Photogates to measure speed
- Ammeter

Comment: Think what torque is and, ask yourself if it's possible without using a mechanical load of some type or other.

Comment: "finding a way to maintain the relatively constant torque whilst changing its speed" are you required to find a completely *automatic* system? Or can you include periodic operator intervention in the "system"?

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "photogates"? Are you talking about CdS photoresistors (aka CdS photocells), photodiodes, phototransistors, optocouplers or some other device?

Comment: If the list of parts includes a second motor, connect their shafts, and control the torque on the first (motor) by controlling the resistive load on the second (generator).

Answer (score 1):

To maintain a constant torque, you need to maintain a constant current.

You need to find a way of getting a constant current with the box of bits that you have. Unfortunately, there's nothing in there that you could build a constant current source that 'just works'.

What you can do is use the power supply variable voltage control, in conjunction with the ammeter and resistor, to keep on adjusting the voltage to maintain a constant measured current through the motor.

For a motor running only at slow speeds, so low back EMF, you can have a current source that stays fairly constant by using a very high voltage from your power supply, and dropping most of it through a fixed resistor. This would need the resistor to have a high enough power rating to handle the resulting heat dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to maintain the torque of a DC motor whilst changing its speed by using simple parts?

Yes, all that would be required is the variable voltage supply.

The torque of a DC shunt motor remains constant till rated speed / rated power is attained, as the armature voltage is increased.

[image]

Beyond rated speed, with constant armature voltage / power, the torque drops while maximum speed is attained, as the field voltage / current is decreased.